# how to align items to have equal width at every resolution

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, responsive-design

I am trying to divide equal width to each div at every resolutions but `max-width` should not br greater than `138px` for div?

But when resolution is changed the `li` at last is gaining width ie not equal to other divs and space around ul row is not evenly distributed , some space is remaining to right?

How to fix that? Any approach?

## .css

```
  .flex-container {
      display: flex;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .flex-container > li{
      background-color: DodgerBlue;
      color: white;
      width: 100px;
      margin: 10px;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 75px;
      font-size: 30px;
      flex-basis: 138px;
```

### .ts

```
data = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW","Saab", "Volvo", "BMW","Saab", "Volvo", "BMW",....]
```

### .html

```
   <ulclass="flex-container" *ngFor="let items of data">
      <li style="flex-grow: 1">1</li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use A Percentage Of The Available Space http://learnlayout.com/percent.html eg

```
.flex-container > div {
     width: 10%;  //Uses 10% of available space
     // OR
     width: 10vw; //Uses 10% of viewport width
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS-Tricks has a [very good guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to flex and here is what is says about `flex-basis`.

> This defines the default size of an element before the remaining space is distributed.

The remaining space is getting filled with the last item. You should get rid of `flex-basis` and either use percentages (or some kind of defined width) or rethink using flexbox and replace it with css grid.